# Service Worker doesn't get data from cache

Tags: caching, browser-cache, service-worker

Task: Offline first;
I have some pages (which end in `?ind${number}.html` and these pages are not caching. I resolve this problem with passing a second argument onto `caches.match(event.request.url))`

```
let CACHE = 'network-or-cache-v1';

self.addEventListener('install', function(event){
  let offlinePage = new Request('/index.html');
  self.skipWaiting();
  event.waitUntil(
    caches
        .open(CACHE)
        .then((cache) => cache.addAll(arrayToCache))
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event){
  const url = new URL(event.request.url);
  console.log(url);
  caches.match(event.request.url, {ignoreSearch: true}).then(function(response) {
    return response || fetch(event.request);
  })
  event.waitUntil(update(event.request));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a new request object and then pass it in to caches.match like

```
 const requestNew = new Request(event.request, {ignoreSearch: 'true' });
 caches.match(requestNew).then(///)
```

Comment: Also If there is a cache miss you are fetching from the network and then you are probably fetching again when you update. You can just add to the cache when you fetch from network and only update when you respond from cache to save a trip to network and save data for the user. @natalia-aga